# __repr__ formating issues: I need to get outcome: Pizza('M', set()), instead I'm getting: Pizza (M, set()). How can I fix it? Below is the code

Tags: python, formatting

I need to get outcome: `Pizza('M', set())`, instead I'm getting: `Pizza (M, set())`
Below is the code. How can I fix it?

```
def __init__(self, size='M', topping=set()):
     self.p=size
     self.t=topping  
def __repr__(self):
     return f'Pizza({self.p},{self.t})'
```

Comment: Use `return f'Pizza({repr(self.p)},{repr(self.t)})'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**repr** function returns a string, so you see the M in the sentence but not 'M'.
if you want 'M', you can change the return string:(use the escape character)
f'Pizza(\'{self.p}\',{self.t})'